# pull Promise result outside of a nested map react js

Tags: async-await, nested, es6-promise

I'm working at a React app and I need to loop inside an array containing objects with this structure:

```
const servers = [
  {
    name: "Server A",
    url: "https://server-one.com/version",
    accessToken: "yJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC",
    subVersions: [
      {
        name: "Subversion A1",
        ip: "https://10.4.20/version",
        accessToken: "yJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC"
      },
      {
        name: "Subversion A2",
        ip: "https://10.4.20/v1/version",
        accessToken: "yJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLCyJ0eXAiOiJKV1QiLC"
      }
                 ]
  },
  // ... more servers obj with the same structure
]
```

and I need to fetch information about the server versions via api calls to the `url` (or `ip`) and return an array of objects that looks like this:

```
[
  {
    name: "Server A",
    version: "1.0.1",
    subVersions: [
      {
        name: "Subversion A1",
        version: "1.0.0"
      },
      {
        name: "Subversion A2",
        version: "1.0.0"
      },
            ]
   }  
]
```

I'm doing is the following: the `fetch()` method will call `fetchVersion()` (which returns the main server version), and then it maps inside all the subVersions to fetch them too.

I'm struggling to get the `result.data` of the subVersions fetch out of that nested map you can see below.

I've tried to:

1. return the data at every iteration
2. pushing the data inside an array and try to return it at the end of the iterations
3. returning the array of data or returning a new Promise that resolves the array of data

But nothing. I can see the right data at the most nested map, but outside I either get a
`Promise { <pending> }` array or an empty one.

Sorry if the code looks messy, I hope it makes sense.

```
const fetchVersion = server =>
  axios
    .get(server.url, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${server.accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      timeout: 30000
    })
    .then(result => new Promise(resolve => resolve(result.data)));

const fetchSubVersion = subVersion =>
  axios
    .get(subVersion.ip, {
      headers: {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${subVersion.accessToken}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json"
      },
      timeout: 30000
    })
    .then(result => new Promise(resolve => resolve(result.data)));

Class Servers {
  constructor(servers = []) {
    this.servers = servers ;
  }

fetch() {
// ==== this map below is the problematic part =====

const subVersions = this.servers.map(server => {
      var subVersArr = server.subVersions.map(
        async server.subVersions.map(subVersion => 
          await fetchSubVersions(subVersion)
            .catch(() => ({ data: {} }))
            .then(result => new Promise(resolve => resolve(result.data)));
            });
        })
    );
    
    return Promise.all(subVersArr)
        .catch(() => ({ data: {} }))
        .then(data => {
          console.log("data", data); // <- I see the data here correctly
          return data;
        });
    };
// ======= till here ============


const fetches = this.servers.map(server =>
    fetchVersion(server)
        .catch(() => ({ data: {} }))
        .then(result => {
       console.log("subVersions", subVersions(server)); <- but not here
     return {
          name: server.name,
          versions: result.data,
          subVersions: subVersions(server), // should contain the result of the 
                                              problematic map above
          }
        }))
    );

    return Promise.all(fetches);
  }
```

Thanks for the help!!

Comment: Can you please format and highlight code? I don't think it's even syntactically correct and it's quite difficult to provide feedback on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How are you calling your fetch function? You should await it wherever you are calling it.

Like this:

```
async dummyFunction() {
   await fetch();
}
```

Comment: hi, thanks for replying. I'm calling fetch() in another file. the data comes through, apart from the Promise I'm having troubles with

Comment: Thank you Noah! much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

I finally figured it out. What I didn't have clear is that `then()` returns a promise itself, so all I had to just do `subVersion: await subVersions(server)` and the data is there.